# Animate images within video in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I want to add different images with animation in video.
I have user AVMutableAudioCompostion for this.
I have get a success while playing with two images.Two images are animating properly.
But when I am trying to animate more than three images, I have facing issue with final video.
Final video animate only last two images.
I have pasted code snippet.

```
NSArray *imgArray = @[@"Logo3.png",@"Logo2.png",@"Logo1.png",@"Logo4.png",@"Logo5.png"];
 NSMutableArray *layers = [NSMutableArray new];
CGFloat timeOffset = 0.0f;

for (NSString *imgName in imgArray) {
    UIImage *animationImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
    CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [overlayLayer setContents:(id)[animationImage CGImage]];
    overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10,  size.height/2 - 200, 103, 79);
    [overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];


    CABasicAnimation *animation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"hidden"];
    animation.repeatCount=HUGE_VALF;
    //        animation.autoreverses=YES;
//        animation.cumulative = YES;

    // animate from invisible to fully visible
    animation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    animation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];


//        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        animation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero + timeOffset;
        animation.duration = .5f;
        animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    [overlayLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];

    [layers addObject:overlayLayer];
    timeOffset += 0.5f;




}


CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);


videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];

  for (CALayer *layer in layers){
    [parentLayer addSublayer:layer];
}


composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                             videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
```

Comment: Is the video necessary? You could use `UIImageView`'s `animationImages` property to loop through an array of images.

Comment: yeah @rounak, Video is necessary, basically i want to add some clipart with animation in video. and Thanks for showing interest in my question.

Comment: I have get the success.Animation with Video composition is adding layers over video before starting the animation. I want to continuous animation.And clipart will be add one after another with animation.Please help..Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone got the solution then please upload your new code.Because I am having same problem.

Comment: same problem we also facing if any one knows , Please post code

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is in this line:

```
[overlayLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

The "forKey" value here is actually an arbitrary user-defined string for the animation name. If you use the same key, you overwrite previous animations.  Try changing the forKey name each time through the loop.

The keyPath property of the CABasicAnimation is what actually tells the animate which property to change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No I am changing keypath value of CABasicAnimation.But still I am facing issue. Is there any way to change/animate images over video layer of composition.

Comment: Are you now using a different "forKey" value in each iteration of your loop?  If you continually overwrite it, in my experience you will see the problem you are describing (earlier iterations do NOT animate, this is because you are overwriting the instruction).

Comment: Yeah @Tim, I have used below snippet for this.                 [overlayLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"amimateOpacity%d",i]]; where i is current loop count.

Comment: Basically I want to add different animated faces at specific time of videos.